# Use multiple Powershell commands in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

In the method shown here, I would like to use multiple PowerShell cmdlets. How can I do that? Like in a PowerShell window, I do a Import Module and then run a command `Start-Db`. How can I do the same in this method? I am able to run `Import-module` command successfully, but how can I add another command?

```
[Fact]
public void TestGetRecordings()
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddCommand( "Import-Module" ).AddArgument( "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\\PSModules\\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator" );
    ps.Invoke();
    ps.Commands.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [AddStatement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addstatement?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to add multiple commands:

```
ps
  .AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("C:\\ProgramFiles\\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\\PSModules\\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator")
  .AddStatement() // <= this is equivalent to writing ";" in PowerShell
  .AddCommand("Start-Db").AddArgument("...")
  .Invoke();
```

Comment: i also have this command "$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Emulator " How can I put that in above method and then i have to execute this command "New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'NewlyCreatedDatabase' -AutoscaleThroughput 40000"

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint If you search for that you will find examples

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely lazy hack to the issue and you will likely get a far better answer before I will even be near a PC...but why not just write the script to a powershell file?

You can then execute it and keep it for future use...or if need be for any reason, delete it after the command to execute the script returns using a function that waits for it to complete?

Comment: can you share a code example if you have one already

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint As I said I was away from my PC and on the way to sleep honestly or i would have brought up C# and found the proper code as above. Writing a file is simple in C# as is ShellExecute, I'm not much of a PowerShell user so i thought you had a basic knowledge of C# to have got that far. Sorry...seems you have gotten your answer anyways, though i do sometimes prefer the external file method. If your still interested in using that method, gladly. Let me know.